# Windows Phone ListBox Scroll to end

Tags: listbox, windows-phone

How call some function when User scroll ListBox to end?
I try ro use `ScrollToBottom` bit this doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

myListBox.ScrollIntoView(myListBox.Items.Count);

The above will not work if your listbox item is a control, the reason is this scrolls to the top of the item and not the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This works.  Set the ListBox to not scroll, then add a ScrollViewer around it.  Now in your code behind you can set the ScrollViewer to whatever you want.

XAML:

```
<!--Disable the ListBox scroll and add a ScrollViewer so we have control over the scroll position.-->
    <ScrollViewer 
             Name="scrlvwrListBoxMessages"
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <ListBox x:Name="lstbxMessages"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
</ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Code:

```
    private void ScrollToBottom()
    {
        //Scroll to the bottom.
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            this.scrlvwrListBoxMessages.ScrollToVerticalOffset(double.MaxValue);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no method named "ScrollToBottom" in [Silverlight ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Try this :

```
myListBox.ScrollIntoView(myListBox.Items.Count);
```